# How to insert special character in a numerical value in R

Tags: r, object

my object is `x <- 20140323`
i want to change extract it like this `2014-03-23` how can i change it I tried following code

```
 1. z1 <- 20141103  z1[1[1]]   id <-1  z2 <-   
    numeric(length(z1)+length(id))  z2[id] <- "-"  z2[!is.na(z2)] <- z1

      View(z2) v[3,extrat="true"] <- "-"
```

Comment: it is very obscure to me what you want to do. Your data `x` looks like a date and you want to convert it into a date format like `Date` class or `POSIXct` /`POSIXlt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")
```